# Express session cannot set property user of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

I am trying to log in my user through **postman** and each time I try I get the error

> Cannot set property 'user' of undefined

I console logged out the user and was able to confirm that a user was being returned from the db query.

**adminController**

```js
exports.postAdminLogin = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userToFind = req.body.username,
        password = req.body.password;
    // Get data from the db that should be displayed  to user client
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({username: userToFind});
        // If no user is found send 404 status and message
        if (!user) {
            return res.status(422).send('Invalid email or password');
        }
        // If a user is found compare password with the password passed from the request
        return bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
        // If password matches
            .then(doMatch => {
                if (doMatch) {
                    req.session.isLoggedIn = true;
                    req.session.username = user.username;
                    res.session.user = user;
                    return req.session.save(err => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(`Error when trying to login with err ${err}`);
                        }
                        res.status(200);
                        next();
                    })
                }
            })
            // If bcrypt encounters an error
            .catch(err => {
                res.status(500).send(`This is the error ${err}`);
            });
        // If an error occurs when finding a user from the db
    } catch (err) {
        err ? res.status(500).send(err) : console.log('No user found')
    }
    next()
};
```

**server.js**

```js
const path = require("path"),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express();
require('dotenv/config');

// imported dependencies
const bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    session = require('express-session'),
    MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session),
    cors = require('cors'),
    log = console.log,
    User = require('./models/User');

    // Mongo Db Storage
const dbStorage = new MongoDBStore({
    uri: process.env.DATABASE_SESSION_URI,
    collection: 'sessions'
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.session.user) {
        return next();
    }
    User.findById(req.session.user)
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return next();
            }
            req.user = user;
            next()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            next(new Error(err))
        });
});

// where to find routes
const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const menuRoutes = require("./routes/menu");

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(500);
    next();
});

// session config
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: process.env.DATABASE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

// points to static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: dbStorage
}));

app.use('/admin', adminRoutes);
// app.use('/menu', menuRoutes);

// production db
mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => {
        log(`Connected to the database`);
        app.listen(process.env.SERVER_PORT, err => {
        err ? log(`Error occurred trying to connect to port: ${process.env.SERVER_PORT} with err code: ${err}`) : log(`Server connected on port: ${process.env.SERVER_PORT}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    });
```

I want the user to be able to log in and store the session to the db

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing session twice.
Here:

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: process.env.DATABASE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

and here:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: dbStorage
}));
```

remove one of them.

Then you need to move the session initialization up above any code that is trying to access session.

This is first time you are trying to access session.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    next();
});
```

so you need to place session initialization above that.

```
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: dbStorage
}));

// now you can access session
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn;
    next();
});
```

Comment: Hey, That was a super late night oversight adding express session twice. I also made the other changes you suggested and I am still getting the same error. I will continue to try other things as well as report back if/when I get it to work correctly

Comment: You should also add the error event handler for mongodb `dbStorage.on('error',function(error) { console.log(error); });`

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the session config above the routes:

```
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: process.env.DATABASE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

const adminRoutes = require("./routes/admin");
const menuRoutes = require("./routes/menu");
```